# Hide/show page item base on specific values from selected list in apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm using Oracle Apex 19.1 version and i'm very new to apex. I m working on a product form. Where under product type item, it consist of total 5 products display in a selection list. When user select product a or b or d from the list, then accessories page item and plan page item will show in the form. When user select product c or e under product type, accessories page item and plan page item will be hide from the form.

I tried to achieve by setting dynamic action, 'event' set to change, 'selection type' set to items, 
'item(s)' set to product_type

under client-side condition, 'Item' set to item=value, 'item' set to product_type, 'value' set to a,b,d. I realise value condition does not accept more than one value. Is there a way to over come this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of declarative variations when it comes to testing some condition.

[image: server condition options]

Where the values of item/expression 1 are respectively

- P1_ITEM
- A:B:C

I would try use one of these first over using a PL/SQL expression, because performance [can be an issue](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/05/performance-of-apex-conditions.html) depending on how prevalent these conditions become.

Some conditions simply need some nested/compound expression - I prefer the simple PL/SQL expession. If the expression evaluates true, then you'll see the component.

```
:P1_VALUE in ('a', 'b', 'd') and sec.check('blah') = 'Y'
```

Comment: I follow suggest setting under server-side condition, 'type' set to item is in colon delimited list, 'item' set to product_type, 'list' set to a:b:d. but it doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the literals required, as that can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer functions that return Boolean (instead of "item = value" condition type).

In your case, that would be

```
return :P1_PRODUCT_TYPE in ('a', 'b', 'd');
```

used in accessories and plan page items' "Server side condition".

As of Select List item, change its "Page action on selection" to "Redirect and set value".

Comment: there is no return Boolean option from 'type' selection under client-side condition. Could you guide where set? under dynamic action setting or true action setting?

Comment: I guess it is about misunderstanding (my fault, sorry). I edited my message and added some more info. Have a look, please. I just tried it, *works* (i.e. displays/hides page items depending on Select List item's value).

Comment: Apologize I not quite understand yet. Under plan page item, I have "set page action on selection" to "Redirect and set value". Under "server-side condition" I choose pl/sql expression and enter "return product_type in ('a', 'b', 'd');", but I get error when I validate the query. Also do I need to set dynamic action under for plan page item?

Comment: No; don't use "PL/SQL expression" but **PL/SQL function body** which will return Boolean. Put `return product_type in ('a', 'b', 'd');` in there. You don't need dynamic action because "redirect and set value" will do that job.

Comment: When I enter "return product_type in ('a', 'b', 'd'); under PL/SQL function body, it gives me error ORA-06550: line 1, column 131: PLS-00201: identifier 'product_type' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 124: PL/SQL: Statement ignored.

Comment: Probably so; "product_type" should be item name. If it is page 1, then its name might be P1_PRODUCT_TYPE so it would then be `return :P1_PRODUCT_TYPE in ('a', 'b', 'd');`. Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: If since we set condition on service-side, when do hide/show page item action will be execute? when we change product type ? or when we press create button? Just wonder what kind of action will trigger  that?

Comment: somehow plan and accessories page item hide from my form even I select correct product_type 'a', which suppose to show plan and accessories page item, any idea why?

Comment: Your previous question: yes, as soon as you change product type because its "Redirect and set value" will "trigger" server side condition. As of your last question: is there anything left from your previous attempts (dynamic actions, whatever) which might "reverse" what you did last? If you aren't sure, try to create a new - simple - page to test how "solution" I suggested works.

Comment: Somehow it will only trigger when I click create button. But I manage to achieve using another method. I set 'item is in list' in client side condition under dynamic action then define list of values. Thanks for your advice.